# Remove elements from List within the range with lambda

Tags: java

I have a list of timestamps. I need to keep only the first element within a range and remove the rest.

Initial list:

```
AAPL -- 2022-09-28T14:32:53.424494377
AAPL -- 2022-09-28T14:32:58.424494377
AAPL -- 2022-09-28T14:33:03.424494377
AMZN -- 2022-09-28T14:33:08.424494377
AAPL -- 2022-09-28T14:33:13.424494377
MSFT -- 2022-09-28T14:33:18.424494377
AMZN -- 2022-09-28T14:33:23.424494377
MSFT -- 2022-09-28T14:33:28.424494377
AAPL -- 2022-09-28T14:33:33.424494377
AMZN -- 2022-09-28T14:33:38.424494377
AMZN -- 2022-09-28T14:33:43.424494377
AMZN -- 2022-09-28T14:33:48.424494377
AMZN -- 2022-09-28T14:33:53.424494377
AAPL -- 2022-09-28T14:33:58.424494377
AMZN -- 2022-09-28T14:34:03.424494377
AAPL -- 2022-09-28T14:34:08.424494377
AMZN -- 2022-09-28T14:34:13.424494377
AAPL -- 2022-09-28T14:34:18.424494377
AMZN -- 2022-09-28T14:34:23.424494377
```

Let's use 60 sec as a range, then I expect this result:

```
AAPL -- 2022-09-28T14:32:53.424494377
AMZN -- 2022-09-28T14:33:08.424494377
MSFT -- 2022-09-28T14:33:18.424494377
AAPL -- 2022-09-28T14:33:58.424494377
AMZN -- 2022-09-28T14:34:13.424494377
```

My code works, but I use the "old" java loop with some conditions. I would like to reduce unnecessary lines and use lambda to make my code cleaner if it is possible.

The `priceReducer` method is what I want to simplify. The rest of the code is only needed to present you that working example.

```
public class Aaa {
    final static String[] TICKERS = {"AMZN", "MSFT", "AAPL"};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Aaa app = new Aaa();
        List<Price> prices = app.initPrices(20);
        app.priceReducer(prices, 60);
    }
   
    private List<Price> initPrices(int numberOfElements) {
        List<Price> list = new ArrayList<>();
        var now = LocalDateTime.now();
        var index = new AtomicInteger();

        IntStream.range(1, numberOfElements).forEach(i -> list.add(
                new Price(getRandomTicker(), now.plusSeconds(5L * index.incrementAndGet())))
        );
        return list;
    }

    public String getRandomTicker() {
        int rnd = new Random().nextInt(TICKERS.length);
        return TICKERS[rnd];
    }
    
    private void priceReducer(List<Price> prices, int intervalInSecond) {
        System.out.println("-- original list --------------");
        prices.forEach(System.out::println);

        List<Price> reducedList = new ArrayList<>();
        prices.sort(Comparator.comparing(Price::getTradeDate));

        Map<String, LocalDateTime> rangeEnds = new HashMap<>();
        for (Price current : prices) {
            var rangeEnd = rangeEnds.get(current.getTicker());
            if (Objects.isNull(rangeEnd)) {
                reducedList.add(current);
                rangeEnds.put(current.getTicker(), current.getTradeDate().plusSeconds(intervalInSecond));
            } else {
                if (current.getTradeDate().isAfter(rangeEnd)) {
                    reducedList.add(current);
                    rangeEnds.put(current.getTicker(), current.getTradeDate().plusSeconds(intervalInSecond));
                }
            }
        }

        prices.clear();
        prices.addAll(reducedList);
        System.out.println("-- reduced list ---------------");
        prices.forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    class Price {
        LocalDateTime tradeDate;
        String ticker;
        BigDecimal price;

        public Price(String ticker, LocalDateTime tradeDate) {
            this.ticker = ticker;
            this.tradeDate = tradeDate;
        }

        public LocalDateTime getTradeDate() {
            return tradeDate;
        }

        public String getTicker() {
            return ticker;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return ticker + " -- " + tradeDate;
        }
    }
}
```

Is that possible to write a simpler code with lambda for this purpose?

This code will be part of [this](https://github.com/zappee/portfolio-analyzer/tree/feature/portfolio-summary) project.

I use Java 17 LTS.

Comment: The question would be easier to digest if you briefly explain in plain English what method `priceReducer()` is meant to do.

Comment: *Sidenote:* according to the Language naming convention method-names are usually verbs (not nouns) because they represent actions.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest moving the logic of the processing of each `Price current` to a separate method, use `Optional` pipeline to handle nulls with `ifPresentOrElse` etc, then call this method in `prices.stream().forEach()`

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the task using the following techniques:

1. separate the prices for tickers using `Collectors.groupingBy`. this produces a map where key is ticker and value is list of all related prices. this allows separate processing of each ticker.

   ```
   private void priceReducer(List<Price> prices, int intervalInSecond) {
       System.out.println("-- original list --------------");
       prices.forEach(System.out::println);

       List<Price> reducedList = new ArrayList<>();

       // separate prices by ticker
       Map<String, List<Price>> pricesByTicker = prices.stream()
           .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(price -> price.getTicker()));

       // process each ticker's prices separately
       pricesByTicker.values().stream()
           .map(tickerPrices -> reduceForTicker(tickerPrices, intervalInSecond))
           .forEach(reducedTickerPrices -> reducedList.addAll(reducedTickerPrices));

       System.out.println("-- reduced list ---------------");
       reducedList.forEach(System.out::println);
   }
   ```
2. for each ticker: sort the prices by trade date, assign first entry to reduced list, then iteratively remove items from list that are within interval range of last entry of reduced, add first remaining item from prices to reduced, repeat.

   ```
   private List<Price> reduceForTicker(List<Price> tickerPrices, int intervalInSecond) {
       List<Price> reducedList = new ArrayList<>();
       // sort by trade date asc
       tickerPrices.sort(Comparator.comparing(Price::getTradeDate));
       // first item added unconditionally
       reducedList.add(tickerPrices.get(0));

       while (!tickerPrices.isEmpty()) {
           // last item in reducedList signifies current minute
           Price current = reducedList.get(reducedList.size()-1);
           LocalDateTime minuteAfterCurrent = current.getTradeDate().plusSeconds(intervalInSecond);
           // relying on ordered prices, remove all prices within minute after current
           tickerPrices.removeIf(price -> price.getTradeDate().isBefore(minuteAfterCurrent));
           // first item in whatever is left in prices signifies next minute
           if (!tickerPrices.isEmpty()) {
               reducedList.add(tickerPrices.get(0));
           }
       }
       return reducedList;
   }
   ```